# Payment details not showing in one page ajax checkout WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

[image]

I need to make a one page checkout form in woocommerce.
SO in a page,there are 3 steps for user to fill up.

1. form part 1
2. form part 2
3. checkout/ payment page

I show the checkout page via ajax:

```
   function getCheckout(){
    define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT', true );
    echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_checkout]');
    die();
   }
```

[image]
It works correctly, but payment details are not showing. For now I'm using stripe on testing mode. Its not showing the card details saved. Also add new card button also not working.
How to solve this?